# Writing in the Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am getting an exception while trying to connect to the windows azure active directory.
The exception is being thrown in the beginning, in the following command:

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/xxx.onmicrosoft.com");
```

"object not set to an instance of an object"

Any guess?

Comment: what version of ADAL do you use. What version of .NET and what platform (Windows Store, WPF, Windows Phone, Console app, Web app ..)

Comment: This is a web app. #region Assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll, v2.12.0.0 and the .Net version is 4.5

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace? Alternatively: in http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/07/adal-for-netwindows-storewindows-phone-is-now-open-source/ you can find instructions on how to add the ADAL symbols and F11 inside the constructor.

Comment: The only thing I can see is the following (and it doesn't help...)System.NullReferenceException was caught
  _HResult=-2147467261
  _message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  HResult=-2147467261
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Sdm.SelfServices.RA.GraphApi
  StackTrace:
       at Sdm.SelfServices.RA.GraphApi.WaadClient.UpdateClaim(OnlineClaimsTypes claimType, String claimValue)
       at Sdm.SelfServices.RA.Web.Controllers.AssurityController.<ValidatePSIData>d__3.MoveNext()
  InnerException: